# Can I call instance method directly like in included module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, module

If it is possible, How to call or rebuild `SomePluggin` class to call `get_content` method directly in included module, so as to reduce redundant `get_content` in `Pluggin` module?

```
module Cms
  class SomePluggin
    def get_content
      puts "please call me directly"
    end
  end

  module Pluggin
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      after_initialize :pluggin
    end

    attr_writer :pluggin

    def pluggin
      @pluggin ||= SomePluggin.new
    end

    def get_content # Is there any possibility to do this directly?
      pluggin.get_content
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) `get_content` call to `pluggin`:

```
module Pluggin
  delegate :get_content, to: :pluggin
  # ...
end
```